# How do i remove the Safari native Swipe animation on back/next page

Tags: css, safari, swipe-gesture

How do I remove the swipe animation when changing pages in Safari based browsers? (Safari both for iOS and OSX have this).

I have a website that uses ngAnimate to animate between pages. The problem is that every time I swipe on the phone or on a touchpad to go back in Safari, Safari plays a built in animation first.

Is there a way to remove this animation?